# F-bound polymorphism in Scala: concrete subclass not recognized as subtype of generic class

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism

I have a generic type:

```
trait BaseTrait[T <: BaseTrait[T]] {
  self: T =>
  def similar(that: T): Float

}
```

A concrete type:

```
class MyConcrete(val..) extends BaseTrait[MyConcrete]  {
  type Self = MyConcrete
..
  def similar(that: MyConcrete) = {
     return 0.5f // dummy
  }
}
```

I want to write something like this:

```
def create[T <: BaseTrait[T]](..): T = new MyConcrete(..)
```

I get the error:

```
type mismatch;  found: MyConcrete  required: T
```

I was expecting that since MyConcrete is a subtype of BaseTrait, it would work(but I am wrong)

My intention is to hide the construction of MyConcrete so that I can later change the above to MyConcrete2 (which also extends BaseTrait like MyConcrete) and my code which only cares about the BaseTrait interface will not be affected by my change.

How do I write the interface of my create method.

Thanks.

Comment: Self-type annotations constrain the type of concrete (instantiable) subtypes but that constraint does not become part of the external type of the trait or its subtypes unless explicitly mixed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create[T <: BaseTrait[T]](..): T = new MyConcrete(..)
```

That type parameter `T` doesn't make much sense. You are asking *the caller* to tell the method what `T` is, which obviously doesn't work in this scenario. If you were to interpret `T` as something given back from the method (automatically inferred), then still the caller couldn't do much with it.

From the caller's perspective the best you can get is

```
def create(..): BaseTrait[_] = new MyConcrete(..)
```

If on the other hand you want a specific subtype but hide the implementation of `MyConcrete`, you would define a trait

```
trait ConcreteLike extends BaseTrait[ConcreteLike]

class MyConcrete extends ConcreteLike {
  def similar(that: ConcreteLike) = 0.5f
}

def create(): ConcreteLike = new MyConcrete()
```

Comment: I just removed the return value from the create method :)